# Calendar Month Instance is off by one

Tags: java, calendar

Here is my code:

Month is passed in on a loop.  First 0 (since it is January as I type), then 1, and so on.  Next month when it is February, this loop will start from that date.  1, 2, etc.

```
    int thisMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + thisMonth);

    String sMonth = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

In the first loop, `sMonth` is March 2015. 
In the second loop, `sMonth` is March 2015. 
In the third loop, `sMonth` is April 2015. 
In the fourth loop, `sMonth` is May 2015. 
..and so on

As you see, the first month is NOT February as expected.  I believe it is January 29th so that may have some cause as we are so close to February.  But if that is the case, why would this happen twice?

I know since I am not working with unix timestamps things aren't exact, is there away to calculate this where I can at least get accurate month ordering?

Comment: You're setting the date to February 30th, which probably rolls over to March 2nd.

Comment: That makes so much sense!  so I should probably have a February special case then?

Comment: Just set the day-of-month to 1 before changing the month, since you only care about the month anyway.

Comment: Thanks, go ahead and put that as an answer and I'll mark you right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since today is the 30th, you're getting the current date (2015-01-30), and incrementing the month to get 2015-02-30 - which "rolls over" to 2015-03-02 since February doesn't have 30 days.

One way to avoid this problem is to set the day-of-month to 1 before changing the month.